# Daily notification on xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

What is the best way to give the user an option to select time in the day in app and then they will receive a repeated notification on their phone at that time every day. I know there is a way to push notifications with app center and firebase but I just wanted to see if there is an easy way to set up repeated daily notifications with xamarin whether thats with forms or separate for ios and android and let the user choose when. Please let me know if there is a guide, tutorial, or anything I can use for this. I have experience with c# but I am fairly new to xamarin, so I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve `the repeated notification on their phone at that time every day` by sending notofications.

The are two kinds of notifications:

`Remote Notification`(like Firebase, AppCenter you mentioned)

`Local Notification`(schedule a local notification and it will trigger with the time you set).

Base on your requirement, I think local notification is the best option to you.
You can draw a view to let user choose which time to fire , repeate or not and etc. And then set these options to your local Notification.

Here is a sample code of local notification in iOS:

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent ();
content.Title = "Notification Title";
content.Subtitle = "Notification Subtitle";
content.Body = "This is the message body of the notification.";
content.Badge = 1;

var trigger =  UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger (5, false);

var requestID = "sampleRequest";
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier (requestID, content, trigger);

UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest (request, (err) => {
    if (err != null) {
        // Do something with error...
    }
});
```

You should implement it separately for ios and android.

**Here are tutorials in Xamarin:**

For iOS: [enhanced-user-notifications(new since ios 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows) [user-notifications(ios 9 and prior)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/)

For Android: [local-notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications) [Remote-notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/)

Ask me if you have any question.